# Trapezoidal signal frequency spectrum

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum

[image]

[image]

I don't understand why the frequency spectrum of a trapezoidal signal looks like this. I was expecting either a $\mathrm{sinc}$ or a $\mathrm{sinc}^2$, but it seems to be a combination of both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trapezoid can be created by convolving two rectangles with DIFFFERENT width. In your case it's a rectangle of width 2 convolved with a rectangle of width 2.5

So the spectrum is the product of two sinc functions, but with different frequencies. This creates the interference pattern that you see.